# How to use sync adapter with content provider.?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I want to implement sync adapter in my app to a specific data frequently. The documentation provided in the developer site seems hard to understand for me.
Kindly help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a great tutorial at [Udacity Developing android apps](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud853) skip to lesson 6 to sync adapters, this course could solve other problems that you might face.